# Change default package from com.example for Eclipse Android projects

Tags: android, eclipse, package, default

I am using Eclipse 4.2 with Android SDK.

I am wondering if it is possible to change the default package ID `com.example` that shows in the "New Android Application" wizard as you type the application name?

I would like it to default to my own package ID so that I don't need to correct the Package Name field each time.

Is this possible to do? Please explain how.

Comment: The answer is already here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741246/need-help-changing-my-package-name-in-eclipse#_=_

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot change the default; it's hardcoded in the plugin sources.

(For the curious, it's in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.NewProjectPage#SAMPLE_PACKAGE_PREFIX in the ADT code base). We should consider persisting the most recently set package prefix and inserting the parent package next time. Feel free to file an issue for that at http://b.android.com category Component-Tools.

-- Tor

Comment: Hi Tor - I didn't see an issue for this yet, so I created http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=44972. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

With Android Studio not running, edit the file: C:\Users\MyAccount\.AndroidStudio\config\options\options.xml  (replace C: with the installation drive and MyAccount with your account name).

Within the xml file look for "property name="SAVED_COMPANY_DOMAIN" value=" and change the value to what you want.

Comment: This answer is relevant but probably outdated as `SAVED_COMPANY_DOMAIN` is not present anymore. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65130670/4266287)

Comment: this folder doesn't exit

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming here in 2020, the file you are looking for is other.xml
It can be found in your AndroidStudio library under config/options/other.xml
(For mac this is probably ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/options)

Then you can follow the instructions by @Murillo Comino

`<property name = "SAVED_ANDROID_PACKAGE" value = "com.example" />`

EDIT:

As per @Douglas Kazumi 's comment, it is important that AS will be closed while editing this.

Comment: Important detail here found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28400985/4266287) : Android Studio needs to be closed, otherwise it will reset back to the default value.

Comment: this foler doesn't exist

Comment: Why doesn't it offer this setting somewhere in the UI...
There's already so many settings, adding one more wouldn't make it any less needing of that search function xD

Comment: I am using Android Studio from the Jetbrains Toolbox and there seems to be no such file or path to it.

Answer (score 2):

Following user2232952's guidance, for new versions of Android Studio change the value of:

```
<property name = "SAVED_ANDROID_PACKAGE" value = "com.example" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why so many people have right answers with wrong file location...

I've installed android studio 2020.3 with all default settings and the file `others.xml` is in folder

```
C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\options
```

Comment: Works on Windows February 2022.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already created your project, you could go to your AndroidManifest.xml file and update the attribute in the Manifest (root) tag

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your.package.name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Just make sure the rest of your code also reflects this change.

Comment: thnx for that info.  However I would like to set the default package ID so that I don't have to edit it as I'm creating the project.  At the moment, I have no need to alter the package name for existing projects.

Comment: You are getting down votes because you aren't answering the question. The issue isn't changing the package name after the project has been created but changing the eclipse default from "com.example" to something user specific. That way, when a new project is created, the package name is pre-populated with a useful value.

Answer (score -1):

Click the package name and hit Alt+Shift+R and Rename, it will update everything!