# Is it possible to change the default package name prefix for new Android apps (Intellij-IDEA community edition)

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Just getting started with Android development. The JetBrains tutorial emphasizes that the package name should start with "com.your-company-name.xxx". In playing around I've created four test apps, and three out of the four times I forgot to specify the package name correctly. :-(

Can the default package name prefix be specified somewhere?

Incidentally, here's a corresponding question for Eclipse: [Change default package from com.example for Eclipse Android projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484833/change-default-package-from-com-example-for-eclipse-android-projects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible yet, [vote for this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109266).

Comment: OK, hope that results in it getting implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your package in the manifest, attribute "package"

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking if the default package name prefix can be specified somewhere, so it isn't necessary to change it later because I've forgotten to set it correctly when the project was created.