# Android Studio 1.2.2, How to change the default package name for new modules

Tags: java, android, module, package

I am trying to make a new module inside my Android Project. When I go to File > New > New Module... And choose Android Library, the default package name given in the module is always com.example.*****.

Is there a way to set this to not be com.example...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a little blue text saying "edit" at the right of the module package name. click on it and then modify the name

Answer (score 4):

For any COVID-19 survivors, the answer you're looking for is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65130670/1441731

tl;dc -

~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/options/other.xml

`<property name = "SAVED_ANDROID_PACKAGE" value = "com.example" />`

Comment: thanks! Tired of seeing an old company name every time I created a new module.

Comment: "For any COVID-19 survivors" 