# How do I Change default package from com.example for Android Studio Projects?

Tags: android-studio

**I am attempting to change the default package name below**

[image: screenshot of studio]

I have looked at several other stack overflow posts.

[Change default package from com.example for Eclipse Android projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484833/change-default-package-from-com-example-for-eclipse-android-projects/28400985#28400985)

When I looked through the other.xml file

(C:\users\default\appdata\roaming\google\androidstudioxxx)

I see no ability to modify the default package here from com.example to something much more meaningful
[image: Screenshot of other.xml file]