# How to migrate the all the packages from one web application to new web application project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

Hi I have a lot of packages, classes & interfaces in one project in eclipse, I want to move or migrate all these to another project, And then I need to change the name of the packages according to the new project, Is there any shorcut in eclipse to do this? or simply I need to create one by one all the packages and classes (copy paste), Any help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For migrating

1. Right click in your package explorer and select `Import`
2. From pop up select `File System` (Available under `General`)
3. Select source and destination directory where you want to import them.

[image]

**Update:**
Select the package name, and use Refactor -> Rename (Shift+Alt+R) to open the Rename Package dialog

[How to Change the Package Name in Eclipse](http://www.ehow.com/how_7836343_change-package-name-eclipse.html)

Comment: How do I change the package name for the entire folder, Is there any way to change? or I need to change in the every class? right now am changing in every class.

Comment: @sailaja I don't have debugger with me now so I can't tell you exact steps. However you can make use of `refractor` and then `rename`to change package names. May be following link can help you. [need help changing my package name in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741246/need-help-changing-my-package-name-in-eclipse) **AND** [Package renaming in eclipse android project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697899/package-renaming-in-eclipse-android-project)

Comment: @sailaja I updated the answer and added few links that can help you.

Comment: the rename under refactor is disabled, don't know what's wrong

Comment: @sailaja What version of eclipse you are using? May be you need to upgrade then.

Comment: am using Eclipse Helios, sure will upgrade. Thanks for the help