# Eclipse - Running the same project twice

Tags: android, eclipse, multiple-instances

I have managed to create my first app called RoomFinder and it works fine. I have now managed to create RoomFinderNFC which uses NFC technology. To create RoomFinderNFC I created a new workspace and imported/copied Roomfinder into a new workspace. My plan was to have RoomFinder installed on my phone as well as RoomFinderNFC. So I have both the apps installed to demonstrate the differences.

However when I run RoomFinderNFC from eclipse it installs over RoomFinder and vice-versa.

Is there a way to have both apps installed at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: For any reasonable usage, you will need to give the copy a distinct package name.  You can do *most* of this with refactor->rename but may need to clean up a few spots manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your RoomFinderNFC app package name. After changing package name you can run both app on same device on same time. just you need to different different packages name in both app.

may this helpful to you :)

Comment: I've tried Refactor -> Rename but it stills overwrites each time?

Comment: Ok, I followed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741246/need-help-changing-my-package-name-in-eclipse
And it worked. 
I'll give the accept answer as you did point me in the correct way
Thanks